# How to dynamically piece page elements together to form a square?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a number of items with different values. I'd like to represent each item as a square with its size corresponding to its value, where each square is a component of a larger square. All the squares of different sizes fit together to make a larger, perfect square.

Is it possible to do something like this with HTML/CSS? Does anyone know of any resources I that might get me started with the right techniques?

Or would this be better suited to JavaScript or something else?

Comment: This sounds like the horrid beginning of a knapsack problem.

Comment: I'm sure the Ted.com example can be done with CSS3/HTML5 and no JS. What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: There is a mootools plugin that somewhat accomplishes this: http://mootools.net/forge/p/moomasonry

Comment: @Joel, all of them! ... by which I mean, IE6, IE7, IE8 and standards compliant browsers.
@Josh, fortunately I'm still at a very early analysis stage. The boss will be happier with a much simpler solution, but if i could provide something fancy within a reasonable time-frame I will.

Comment: .. just to note, in my previous comment, the phrase "The boss will be happier with.." should be "The boss will be *happy* with.."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a [treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). There seems to be a number of Javascript libraries for accomplishing this kind of visualization, for example the [Javascript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.html), [Treemap in Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/treemap.html) or [this jQuery plugin](http://www.fbtools.com/jquery/treemap/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ted.com](http://www.ted.com/) and see how they're doing something similar. It's pretty cool.

Comment: That is a really cool effect, though I'm 99% sure they do that with Flash.

Comment: I grant you its awesome, but it's also flash and we have no idea to the process of doing it (as well as it's not a perfect square when complete loading).

Comment: @Ender + I will add that 1%. It is flash.